# What does Shading choice of Meshlab actually do?

Tags: meshlab

In Meshlab v2016.12, there is a selection named "Shading" on the right of the window:
[image]

I want to know what each choice of "Shading" actually does to OpenGL renderer. I mean what OpenGL function it calls and what arguments are passed to the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Vert

- Lighting is enabled - `glEnable(GL_LIGHTING)`
- Per vertex normal is sent to GPU as vertex attribute. This forces the GPU to interpolate normals across the triangles. As a result you'll get a smooth shading.

#### Face

- Lighting is enabled - `glEnable(GL_LIGHTING)`
- Per face normal is sent to GPU as vertex attribute. This means for every face, the face normal is copied across all the vertices. This means the GPU ends up interpolating the same normals across the fragments. As a result you'll get a flat shading across the faces.

#### None

- Lighting is disabled - `glDisable(GL_LIGHTING)`